# CSS Centrally align text in input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to centrally align the text inside a selectable button. I have tried:

```
text:align: center (..to the <input>)
```

..but it didn't work.

Following is my html, I am using bootstrap button.

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
      {
         <label class="btn btn-default productButton">
           <input style="text-align: center" type="radio" name="Products" id="@("product" + @product.Id)" autocomplete="off" checked> @product.Description
         </label>
      }
 </div>
```

Comment: You've spelled `center` wrong in the CSS section but a demo would be of more use, Since text is is usually centered by default in inputs...are you in fact trying to center the text in the **label**?

Comment: @Paulie_D it is spelt correctly.  look at the html input style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spell centre as ‘center’.

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input value="blah blah">
```

Comment: it is spelt correctly.  look at the html input style